# Real time Search with Ionic 1.x

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a fairly large product database that I would like to enable user to search in real time.  I tried following the example.  My web service runs fine but I do not see any selectable items.

[How to create a search in real time with angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868800/how-to-create-a-search-in-real-time-with-angularjs)

Comment: Can you share your code with us? Without anything to go by it's hard to see what's wrong. Also, have you checked to see that your web service is definitely returning the required data?

Comment: @AdamBrocklehurst - I have used exactly the same code that is in the URL above for the accepted answer and replaced the http call with my own web service.

Comment: Have you tried putting a console.log(response) in:
someService.search($scope.keywords).then(function(response){
            console.log(response)
            $scope.response = response.data;
        });
to ensure that the returned response is correct? Best to rule that out first.

Comment: @AdamBrocklehurst  - Yes.  That doesn't work.

Comment: it seems like your web service isn't working then, or perhaps doesn't interact correctly using the angular HTTP.post shortcut. First, check the network tab in developer tools to see if you can see anything going on. If nothing shows up there switch from $http.post to $http({
            url: url,
            method: "POST",
            data: postData,
            headers: headers
        })

Comment: try this https://github.com/djett41/ionic-filter-bar

Comment: @VLR this doesn't look like will search through though millions of records based on the string matching.  This solution seems more like using the ng-filter

Answer (score 0):

Using ->take(5)->get(); in my DB Query and then looping through the results to create an array worked.